# Tensorflow object detection on MobileNet, training results oscillate

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection

I'm trying to train ssd MobileNet on my own dataset but my training results are broken. Let me explain what i did.

Basically i followed this tutorial to detect only boats:

https://pythonprogramming.net/introduction-use-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/

I merged two datasets.
The first one i made from 5000 images from https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/photos/of/ships. More or less 20 images for a unique boat. I outsourced the labeling to crowdflower.com.

Second i filtered the COCO dataset for all the boat images and labels.

Both of the label packages i wrote this format to a .csv file:
[filename,width,height,class,xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax]

I merged the datasets and split them in train and test. In total i had around 10000 images with 16000 labeled boats.

From the train and test csv files i generated the tfrecord files just like in the tutorial using this file:
https://github.com/datitran/raccoon_dataset/blob/master/generate_tfrecord.py

My .pbtxt label file contains this:

```
item {
    id: 1
    name: 'boat'
    }
```

Then i used this config file:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config

Changed num of classes to 1. And the paths to corresponding locations.

I have tried learning rates: 0.004, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001, 0,000001.

I'm training on Ubuntu 17.10 with gtx 1060 nvidia 6gb GPU.

The Tensorboard results show oscillating results, for example on total loss, see images:

[Total loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YkUZ.png)

[Tensorboard graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpwh3.png)

When i export an inference graph and run it on a video it seems to draw random boxes. I have looked for solutions by changing parameters in the config file and checking whether the data is in the right format and location which seem to be the case. I'm new to deep learning and machine learning so i'm pretty stuck. If someone can help me find the mistake or has any advise on methods to try, please let me know, i would be very grateful  because it would sort of save my internship project ;). If you need more information let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: shouldn't num_classes be the number of unique boats?

Comment: It is just one class for all boats named 'boat'

Comment: Are you shuffling the training data? The very rigid period in your tensorboard graph makes me think samples are correlated. Alternatively, even smaller learning rates might help

Comment: I shuffled the data before splitting the train test sets, could it be that the marine traffic part of the dataset has too little variation? And i will try a smaller learning rate, and post the results. Thanks!

Comment: Could it be that my dataset has a high bias, too little variation in the images? I took like more or less 20 images of every boat from this link: https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/index/ships/all/destination:2036/per_page:50